# Help understanding the definition of the function space $\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, function-spaces

In René Schilling's *Measures, Integrals and Martingales*, the function space $\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)$ is defined

$$
\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(\mu):=\{u: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: u \in \mathcal{M}(\mathscr{A}), \exists c>0, \mu\{|u| \geqslant c\}=0\}.
$$

Can someone help clarify what $\mu\{|u| \geqslant c\}=0$ means? I assume, first of all, that is should be read $\mu\left(\{|u| \geqslant c\}\right)=0$, but what exactly is the set
$\{|u| \geqslant c\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{|u| \geq c\}$ is the set $\{x \in X : |u(x)| \geq c\}$.

Thus a measurable function $u \in \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)$ if and only if there exists $c > 0$ such that $|u(x)| < c$ for $\mu$-almost every $x$.

The smallest such $c$ is often referred to as the essential supremum of $u$ with respect to $\mu$.

Another way to think about it is that $u$ is in $\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)$ if and only if there exists a function $v$ which is bounded such that $u = v$, $\mu$-a.e.

Comment: So the condition $\mu\{|u| \geqslant c\}=0$ requires that $\{|u| \geqslant c\}=\{x \in X:|u(x)| \geq c\}=\emptyset$, and therefore $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ consists of those functions that are bounded from both above and below?

Comment: Not quite. The condition requires that $\mu(\{x \in X : |u(x)| \geq c\}) = 0$, this does not mean that $\{x \in X : |u(x)| \geq c\} = \emptyset$. One example is if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $X = \mathbb{R}$. Then consider $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = +\infty$ on $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f \in L^\infty(\mu)$ with any $c > 0$.

Comment: Aha, okay. Thank you for the help!